# Setting height and width of CGRect to match the size of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to set the width and height of frame programmatically which should vary with the type of Phone like for iphone5 i have made following settings

```
_splashView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
```

But if i install the app in iphone6 the splashview does not fit properly. so i want to set the values of width and height programmatically so that it can be used with any type of phone.

something like:

```
_splashView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
```

Comment: did you make any effort to search for this yourself?

Comment: While this question is a duplicate you should really be using auto-layout to do this.

Comment: You should really have separate images to cope with the different pixel resolutions and also aspect ratios.  Otherwise your screens will be pixelated or warped depending how you fit the image into the bounds.

Comment: Always use [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds; to get the screen dimensions if you plan on doing it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UIScreen`'s `bounds` property for this, which provides a `CGRect` with the size that you need:

```
_splashView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
```

You can also set distance constraints on four sides of `_splashView` to zero to make the view resize with the screen automatically.